# dnsmasq and mac filter

Tags: ubuntu, dhcp, dnsmasq

Using dnsmasq as DHCP provider, how is it possible to allow only certain mac addresses to get IP address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use dhcp-ignore:

```
dhcp-range=192.168.0.50,192.168.0.150,12h
dhcp-host=08:00:27:CB:23:44,net:allow
dhcp-host=08:00:27:CB:23:45,net:allow
dhcp-host=08:00:27:CB:23:46,net:allow
dhcp-ignore=#allow
```